# How to read emails from shared inbox folder on outlook using Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have access to the folder called **Recalls** on Outlook. I want to read all emails in the **Inbox** subfolder of Recalls using the Graph API. I am using the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test the API. On trying https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders, I am only able to see the subfolders under my email but not the ones under **Recalls** here. My line of thinking is that, since I can see the Recalls folder on my outlook, there must be some way to access it using the Graph API as well. I need help with the right API endpoint or method to access the inbox folder of Recalls. Here is an image to understand the folder structure on Outlook.

[image]

Update: I tried using the users API. Even though I have given consent for the needed permissions, I still have an issue with credentials.

[image]

Comment: To Access a Shared Mailbox you would need to give either the Mail.Read.Shared or Mail.ReadWrite.Shared permission. Your current permission don't give you access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose Select permissions from the more actions button (the 3 dots next to the username)in Graph Explorer you can add the permission from the dialogue eg

[image]